# Вытащить номер записи из поля со списком <select>

Tags: php

Как при помощи php вытащить из поля со списком номер выбранной записи?

Comment: Если не сложно, расширьте свой вопрос, где вы извлекаете номер? В обработчике формы? В парсере HTML-страницы? Есть ли у вас собственная попытка решения вопроса? Она тоже будет уместна и поможет ответить полнее.

Comment: @cheops Я хочу вытащить номер записи из поля со списком, чтобы по нему найти в базе данных соответствующие записи.

Comment: Подробнее распишите вопрос, желательно с вашим кодом, на данный момент ничего не понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я разобрался как это сделать: @intval($_REQUEST['имя поля'])